# Change text in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-tablayout

Please, tell me

First of all in drawable I make selector

tab_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
 android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" 
 android:state_selected="true" />
    <item 
 android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" 
 android:state_selected="false" 
 android:state_focused="false" 
 android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

for active tab tab_background_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

for pasive tab tab_background_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and in styles

```
<style name="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
</style>
```

What I must do than? in Tablelayout? or something alse?

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Xml file on which you are using TabLayout

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabBackground="@color/tab_color"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/toggle_normal_off">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your First Text" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Second Text" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Third Text" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Fourth Text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

This might help you!!!